# Reference for "Every finite $p$-group can be expressed as a section of a powerful $p$-group"

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, p-groups

I was reading about powerful $p$-groups.

> For an odd prime $p$, a finite $p$-group is called powerful if $[G,G] \subseteq G^p$, where $G^p = \langle g^p ~:~ g \in G \rangle$.

and I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_p-group) that

> "Every finite $p$-group can be expressed as a section of a powerful $p$-group".

I was wondering where can I find a reference for this claim?

Also does "section" means "quotient" here? Sorry if I am missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Section usually means a quotient of a subgroup, not necessarily a quotient of the group itself. This is given within Wikipedia itself, which you are pointing to. Did you not follow the link?

Comment: (Your title does not match your quote; given that you were unsure on whether “section” was synonymous with “quotient”, perhaps your title should be accurate as to the quote, not something else)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks. I have corrected the title. Many thanks. Is there any reference you can suggest for the claim?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for pointing out; I missed the link with in the page in the Wikipedia. I understand. Thanks. I am looking for a reference for the claim. Can you please suggest one?

Comment: The place I thought I would have one (Leedham-Green and McKay’s book on the structure of finite $p$-groups) does not seem to have it, and I’m away from office and University resources until Wednesday, unfrotunately.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I understand. Many thanks for your support. If you somehow find this anywhere please share the reference, even if that is after Wednesday. That will be really helpful.